# What is the maximum amount of eigenvectors that a square matrix n x n might have?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

having the following arbitrary matrix:

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1} & \cdots & a_{1,n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{n,1} & \cdots & a_{n,n}
\end{pmatrix}$

What is the maximum amount of (linearly independent) eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $A$ ? How to calculate the actual number of eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $A$?

thanks!

Comment: I suggest you start by [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors).

Comment: Notice that is $v$ is an eigenvector then so are $2v$ and $-17v$ and $\pi v$ and so on. So rather than ask for the number of eigenvectors the sensible question asks for the number of *linearly independent* eigenvectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about $A=I$, how many (linearly independent) eigenvectors does $A$ have?

With regards to computing the eigenvectors/eigenvalues of a general $A$ you have to find pairs $(\lambda,v)$ such that

$$Av=\lambda v.\quad\quad (*)$$

One way to go around this is first compute the possible $\lambda$s by solving for the roots of

$$\det(A-I\lambda).$$

Then compute the corresponding $v$s by solving the linear equations defined by $(*)$.

For more info, I'd recommend you have a look at these [camcasts](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/alternate_bases/eigen_everything/v/linear-algebra--introduction-to-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors).